# Create an NGINX ingress controller in Kubernetes, using Azure

Tags: azure, nginx, kubernetes, terraform, nginx-ingress

I'm working on the setup of a production instance of a .NET Core app, that needs to be deployed in an Azure managed kubernetes cluster, using an NGINX ingress controller. I need to now implement the NGINX ingress controller. There's an existing dev instance, and the provisioning was done using Terraform. From what I've read online so far, it looks like setup of an ingress controller needs to be done fairly manually, but that this can be done using Kubernetes manifests - like in this guide https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/

I'm wondering though if I'm missing something, and if there's some really easy, straightforward way to do this. For example with Minikube, an NGINX ingress controller can be implemented very simply with `minikube addons enable ingress` - see https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#enable-the-ingress-controller. I'm not using Minikube, I'm using full Kubernetes.

The dev and production instances will both run on the same cluster, and the dev pods named `myappname-dev-ngingx-ingress-controller` and `myappname-prod-nginx-ingress-default-backend` are within an `ingress-basic` namespace, and the corresponding pods for prod will be in a `ingress-prod` namespace, to be consistent with how this has been implemented elsewhere in our business. Does this naming scheme indicate that a particular method was probably used to generate these pods? I'm trying to implement things the same way, so that everything is consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out this is the process that's been followed:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-tls